# How to create an order from sales channel and redirect the user to Shopify store for payment?

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

I am working on an e-commerce website similar to E-bay or Amazon, where sellers can list their products.

I have also created a Shopify *Sales Channel* for my e-commerce website, which can import products from Shopify. A Shopify store installs the *Sales Channel App* and their products will be imported to my e-commerce website.

All of this is working fine... now I want to build the last step, which is buy the product. A buyer comes to my e-commerce website and wants to buy a product which has been imported from certain Shopify store. I want to enable the buyer to create an order from my e-commerce website.

According to [Shopify documentation](https://shopify.dev/tutorials/complete-a-sales-channel-payment-with-checkout-api):

> By default, your app can provide checkout links to Shopify's web
>   checkout for each product. This lets your platform use Shopify's web
>   checkout instead of building your own native checkout form. You can
>   direct customers to a checkout link by using the `web_url` parameter of
>   the Checkout API.

This is what I want... I want to allow a buyer in my e-commerce website to create an order and redirect him to Shopify for payment... buy how can I actually implement this? Would I be able to implement this using *Order API*? And how could I redirect the user to Shopify store for payment?

If redirecting user to Shopify store for payment is not an option, then do I need to implement the payment process within my e-commerce using the *Checkout API*? Would anyone be able to give some details about this?

Comment: In DraftOrder API you can get `invoice_url` which is actually a link that can be provided to the customer where he can leave his delivery address and pay for the order. I'm not familiar with Checkout API but it seems like it pretty the same and you can use `web_url` to redirect a customer to finished there checkout.

Comment: @Vladimir: As you suggested, I am creating a `DraftOrder` from my sales channel (my e-commerce) and use the `invoice_url` to send the user to Shopify store for payment, do you know how I can redirect to user back to my sales channel, once the payment is completed?

Comment: What about this? https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/orders/status-tracking/customize-order-status#add-additional-scripts

Comment: Why did you decide to go with `invoice_url` rather than using the `web_url` provided by Checkout API?

Comment: @Vladimir: thanks for your help, I haven't tried that option yet. Not really sure how does the `Checkout API` works...

Comment: Cool, happy that DraftOrder API worked for you. I'll add the initial answer back then.

Answer (score 1):

Use [DraftOrder API](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/orders/draftorder) to create an order. Once created it has the `invoice_url` attribute which can be used to pay and complete that order.

Comment: Thanks for this. So does it mean that my Sales Channel has to create a *Draft Order* and Shopify will give me an `invoice_url`? But how would I use the `invoice_url` for payment? I also don't know how to use the `web_url` to redirect user to Shopify Payment process...