# How to redirect user back to the Sales Channel once the Shopify Payment is completed?

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

I have build a Sales Channel for my e-commerce website. The Sales Channel loads shopify products from Shopify stores to my e-commerce website.

Now I want to implement the `Buy` functionality: the user selects a product in my e-commerce website. I would create a `DraftOrder` and send the draft order to Shopify, shopify would respond with am `invoice-url`.

Now I can redirect the user to this `invoice-url` to make the payment directly through Shopify... but I want to redirect the user back to my e-commerce website, once the payment is completed.

Is it possible to implement this redirect functionality?

---

Note: I had asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61039791/how-to-create-an-order-from-sales-channel-and-redirect-the-user-to-shopify-store) trying to achieve the same goal using *Checkout API*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do too much on the order status page - the page customer gets in once an order is placed and paid. You can add custom scripts on the shop's checkout settings page: [Add Additional Scripts](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/orders/status-tracking/customize-order-status#add-additional-scripts). For example, you can show a message with a link back to your sales channel.

If you're on Shopify Plus you can [customize](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/orders/status-tracking/customize-order-status#edit-the-checkout-liquid-file) `checkout.liquid` directly.